# Window function IGNORE NULLS workaround for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

With the following query I can use the LAG() function to repeat the last non null value of `c` column:

```
SELECT coalesce(open_time, extract(EPOCH from date_trunc('minute', datetime)) * 1000)               open_time,
   coalesce(o, LAG(c) over w)                                                                          o,
   coalesce(h, LAG(c) over w)                                                                          h,
   coalesce(l, LAG(c) over w)                                                                          l,
   coalesce(c, LAG(c) over w)                                                                          c,
   coalesce(v, 0)                                                                                      v,
   coalesce(close_time, extract(EPOCH from date_trunc('minute', datetime)) * 1000 + ((60000 * 1) - 1)) close_time
from temporary_timeframe 
window w as (order by datetime);
```

Getting the following result:

[image]

But I need to repeat the value of the `c` column while the current column value is null. I see that if PostgreSQL supports `IGNORE NULLS` attribute on window functions this would be solved. How to solve this without `IGNORE NULLS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LAG() doesn't repeat the last non null value.

<sub>Quoted from docs</sub>

> returns value evaluated at the row that is offset rows before the current row within the partition; if there is no such row, instead return default (which must be of the same type as value)

But you can set a partition depending on one column value and then use firts_value() function.

> ```
> create table tbl (id int, a int, b int, c int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values
> (1, 12, 4, 3),
> (2, 10, 10, 5),
> (3, 6, 12, 23),
> (4, 6, null, 10),
> (5, 7, null, 4),
> (6, 1, 8, 10),
> (7, 4, null, 3);
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select id, a, first_value(b) over (partition by grp) as b, c
> from (
>       select id, a, b, c, 
>              sum(case when b is not null then 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
>       from   tbl
>      ) t
> ```
>
> ```
> id |  a |  b |  c
> -: | -: | -: | -:
>  1 | 12 |  4 |  3
>  2 | 10 | 10 |  5
>  3 |  6 | 12 | 23
>  4 |  6 | 12 | 10
>  5 |  7 | 12 |  4
>  6 |  1 |  8 | 10
>  7 |  4 |  8 |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=362d59c44ab59d7d3a59fdbf3e7bdcf6)*